# Symhony помочь написать запрос для вывода всех резюме для каждой компании

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, запрос, symfony

Проблема заключается в том, чтобы вывести для компании отправленные туда резюме. У меня есть три таблицы: summary, company и summary_company. Вот схема таблиц со связами в редакторе:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пока написала вот такой вариант реализации запроса (он рабочий, но неправильный, потому что отображает неверные данные):

```
 $companySummaries = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()
        ->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select('s')
        ->from(Summary::class, 's')
        ->innerJoin(SummaryCompany::class, 'sc', 'with', 's.id = sc.summaries')
        ->where('sc.id = '.$company->getId())
        ->orderBy('s.id', 'ASC')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
        dd($companySummaries);
```

А вот другой вариант, который по идеи должен быть рабочим, но какая-то беда с Companies:

```
 $companySummaries = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()
        ->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select('sc')
        ->from(SummaryCompany::class, 'sc')
        ->leftJoin(Company::class, 'c', 'with', 'sc.companies = c.id')
        ->leftJoin(Summary::class, 's', 'with', 'sc.summaries = s.id')
        ->where('sc.companies = '.$company->getId())
        ->orderBy('sc.id', 'ASC')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
        dd($companySummaries);
```

Comment: А можно текст ошибки ксли она есть или какого рода беда с companies?

Answer (score 0):

Немного бы подтянуть SQL, т.к. видно, что явные проблемы с самой выборкой.

```
    /**
     * SummaryRepository - запрос должен быть от резюме.
     *
     * @param Company $company
     * 
     * @return array
     */
    public function getSummaries(Company $company): array
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('s')
            ->leftJoin('s.company', 'c')
            ->andWhere('c.id = :comapny_id')
            ->setParameter('comapny_id', $company->getId())
            ->orderBy('s.id', 'ASC')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
    }
```

Данный запрос вернет все сущности Summary для конкретной компании.

---

Если постараться написать еще проще, то:

```
/** @var $company Company */
$this->summaryRepository->findBy(['company' => $company]);
```

Doctrine довольная умная ORM, чтобы собрать запрос не по столбцу в таблице, а по свойству в вашей сущности, data-mapper как никак.

---

Чтобы это все добро отработало как надо, единственное, что должно быть реализовано, это связь с компанией (тип связи может быть другой, главное, чтобы мы ссылались на необходимую сущность и могли ее join-ить):

```
class Summary ...

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=Company::class)
 */
private Comapny $company;
```